# Need help fixing and formatting my code in Python

Tags: python

> Primary U.S. interstate highways are numbered 1-99.
> Odd numbers (like the 5 or 95) go north/south, and evens (like the 10 or 90) go east/west.
> Auxiliary highways are numbered 100-999, and service the primary highway indicated by the rightmost two digits. Thus, I-405 services I-5, and I-290 services I-90.

> Given a highway number, indicate whether it is a primary or auxiliary highway. If auxiliary, indicate what primary highway it serves. Also indicate if the (primary) highway runs north/south or east/west.

> Ex: If the input is:
> `90`
> the output is:
> `I-90 is primary, going east/west.`
> Ex: If the input is:
> `290`
> the output is:
> `I-290 is auxiliary, serving I-90, going east/west.`
> Ex: If the input is:
> `0`
> the output is:
> `0 is not a valid interstate highway number.`

**My Code:**

```
highway_number = int(input("Enter highway number: "))

# output if the highway is invalid

if  ((highway_number <1) or (highway_number >999)):
   print (' {} is not a valid highway number'.format (highway_number))
else: # valid

   if (highway_number >99):
      print ( ' I-{} is a auxillary highway '.format (highway_number))
# serves the primary interstate highway
   primary_number = highway_number % 100

print (' serving I-{}'.format(primary_number))
else: # must be 1-99 and it is  primary interstate highway
primary_interstate_highway = highway_number
print (' I-{} is a primary interstate highway'.format(highway_number))
# direction

if (primary_interstate_highway %2) == 0): #Event
print('going east/west')
else: #odd
print('going south/north')
```

This is where the error is currently.

[image]

Comment: We don't need your assignment text to tell you that `if` and `else` statements need to be vertically aligned, code within them needs indented, and two else's cannot follow each other

Comment: The indentation is wrong. An `else` must line up vertically with a previous `if`.

Comment: I tried that as well, however whenever I try it that way it says unexpected indent.

Comment: If your instructor cannot debug simple indentation errors in a class teaching Python, I have some serious concerns about the quality of the program you find yourself in.

Comment: Why is there an else statement after `print (' serving I-{}'.format(primary_number))`?

Comment: @MatthewMcMahan That’s probably because the line before it must also match the expected indentation. Have you reviewed the indentation-sensitive nature of the language and how it works in your course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need nested checks at all, since each part is its own conditional.

You can also use intermediate variables for each condition, which would make it easier to use in your final output

Notice that each `if` has an (optional) matching `else` on the same vertical indentation line

```
# Get and check input
highway_number = int(input("Enter highway number: "))
if highway_number < 1 or highway_number > 999:
  print (' {} is not a valid highway number'.format (highway_number))
  quit()

# Type + serving
if highway_number > 100:
  road_type = 'auxiliary'
  serving = str(highway_number % 100)
else:
  road_type = 'primary'
  serving = ''

# Direction
if highway_number % 2 == 0:
  going = 'east/west'
else:
  going = 'north/south'

# Create output
output = ['I-{}'.format(highway_number), 'is', road_type + ',']
if serving:
  output.extend(['serving', 'I-{},'.format(serving)])
output.extend(['going', going])
print(' '.join(output))
```

Comment: Thank you, I was just writing the way he was showing us.

Comment: IMO, there is nothing wrong with doing things different from the professor. Especially if he learns something himself from it

Comment: I agree, however I had assumed the professor wasn't going to write a code full of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code misses an `if` or an `elif`. Basing on the Python Syntax,`if statements` should be like this:

```
if (statement):
    code

elif (statement):    # elif is optional when you only have two statements to compare
    code

else:         # else is the default statement, if all upper statements aren't met, then this will run instead
    code
```

So in your code, you either add another `if` or edit `else` to `elif`. Or as others have noted you should `intend` the `else` statement. Here is the code with some minor fixes:

```py
highway_number = int(input("Enter highway number: "))

# output if the highway is invalid

if  ((highway_number <1) or (highway_number >999)):
   print (' {} is not a valid highway number'.format (highway_number))
   
   
else: # valid

    if (highway_number >99):
        print ( ' I-{} is a auxillary highway '.format (highway_number)) # the if block statement wasn't indented
        # serves the primary interstate highway
        primary_number = highway_number % 100

        print (' serving I-{}'.format(primary_number))
    else: # must be 1-99 and it is  primary interstate highway
    
        primary_interstate_highway = highway_number
        print (' I-{} is a primary interstate highway'.format(highway_number))
        
# direction

if (primary_interstate_highway %2) == 0: #Event ; here you had an extra ")"
    print('going east/west')
else: #odd
    print('going south/north')
```

Be more careful with indentation because it is **4 spaces** and not 3 or **tab** will work.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some Indent and also close and open parenthesis and global variable I mean outer scope:

```
highway_number = int(input("Enter highway number: "))

# output if the highway is invalid
primary_number = []
primary_interstate_highway = ''
if  ((highway_number <1) or (highway_number >999)):
   print (' {} is not a valid highway number'.format (highway_number))
else: # valid

   if (highway_number >99):
      print ( ' I-{} is a auxillary highway '.format (highway_number))
# serves the primary interstate highway
      primary_number = highway_number % 100

      print (' serving I-{}'.format(primary_number))
   else: # must be 1-99 and it is  primary interstate highway
      primary_interstate_highway = highway_number
      print (' I-{} is a primary interstate highway'.format(highway_number))
# direction

   if ((int(primary_interstate_highway) %2) == 0): #Event

      print('going east/west')

   else: #odd
      print('going south/north')
```

Comment: This is working for the initial code, however I get an error when entering a number of 99 saying " if ((int(primary_interstate_highway) %2) == 0): #Event
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: convert all to ineger like ((int(primary_interstate_highway) %2) == 0)